# What happens if a method is called too many times at the same time

Tags: java, memory-management

Let us say that I have a method that writes to a file or database. What if different parts of application calls this method too many times at the same time or in same interval of time. All those method calls are maintained in some stack/queue in memory and wait for previous requests to be served ?

Comment: Write into a file it should be [ThreadSafet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) and for the datebase you should be carefull with the  [Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Comment: If the method is accepting the file identity as a parameter, and all the callers are targeting different files, and the method does not foolishly make use of static variables, then the individual operations will each complete as if they were the only one on the machine.

Comment: If you have a *multithread* program and many threads call methods (if you think about *memory management* it doesn't matter if it's the same method or different methods) at the same time, will be allocated a specific memory for each method into the *stack* area (in the RAM memory). When you reach the maximum size of *stack* and you try to call another method, program will end with an `Exception`.

Comment: @GiulioBiagini - But each of the threads has its own stack.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to the same file is platform dependent, like Unix allows concurrent writes to the same file. 
You  need to see the synchronization techniques - how you want to manage the read write operations. 
If you see from DB perspective the db engine handles it properly - whichever comes first will be served. The next insert would depend on the first insert(in case you already inserted with the same key in the previous operation - then obviously it ll throw an exception)

Also I would say if different parts of your application are appending data to the same file at the same time - there could be design flaw and you need to reconsider the design